# How to push hot fixed changes on old tag

Tags: git, github

I want pull old tag from master branch and want to apply hot fixed changes on it. Then want to push the changes on old tag only.

Comment: I don't want commit it new tag want to do it on old tag only/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Checkout your tag (you will be in detached head)
2. Checkout new branch (your base line is your tag sha-1)
3. commit your changes
4. move the tag to the new commit
   `git tag -a <sha-1> -f` This will "move" the tag from the old commit to the   new one commit

Comment: But how to push these modified tag to master branch again. Because when i push git push origin <version> then getting below error.

"Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote"

Comment: add the `-f` (force flag)  `git push -f ...`